# Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date when using CASE WHEN and return Column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some question. I have some query `CASE WHEN` like this and get an error:

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Code:

```
CASE
    WHEN [AVL] = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN [DATE_1] IS NOT NULL THEN [DATE_1] 
    WHEN [DATE_2] IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DD, +2, [DATE_2])
END AS [ETA]
```

The columns `DATE_1` and `DATE_2` are of type `date`, but when I running this query, I get the error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

I want the output column as `date`, or this column convert date as `nvarchar` or string like I use `CONVERT(nvarchar, [DATE_1], 23]` but I have some error too like this.

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2021-11-06' to data type int.

So many thanks if I get an answer, thank you.

Comment: `THEN 1` , 1 is not a date definetly. Replace it with a date value you want.  For example `THEN datefromparts(2021, 1, 1)`

Comment: but i have condition if [AVL] 0 then 0, and cannot using datefromparts(2021, 1, 1), because have error "Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.
"

Comment: Only you can know what day you want when `[AVL]=0`. Construct it at will.

Comment: yes, because 0 day is not available on SQL format, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my answer

because AVL is int we must

```
 CASE
    WHEN [AVL] = 1 THEN '1' --datefromparts(1900, 1, 1)
    WHEN [DATE_1] IS NOT NULL THEN convert(nvarchar(10),[DATE_1])  
    WHEN [DATE_2] IS NOT NULL THEN cast(DATEADD(DD,+2,[DATE]_2) as varchar)
```

because I want the output is string or nvarchar

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use - even in a `cast` or `convert` like here.

Comment: If you're returning a `varchar` though, the value is no longer a date. I also find it quite odd you `CONVERT` one expression and `CAST` the other.